# what's wrong with sublime text 2 for this code?

Tags: c

i wrote this c code in sublime text 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    m = fib(n);
    printf("%d", m);
    return 0;
}
int fib(int n)
    {
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if( n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib( n - 2);
}
```

but i when i build it, the console comes following fault:

```
/home/shieh/program.c: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/shieh/program.c:6:14: error: ‘fib’ was not declared in this scope
     m = fib(n);
              ^
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
```

however, this c code could be accepted by an online testing platform.Anyone could help me fix this problem?
I am confused now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `declare` your function's `before` you call it! Otherwise the function call in `main` can't be done, since at `compilation time` the function isn't known!(The compiler goes from the top to the bottom!) So try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n) {

    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if( n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib( n - 2);
}

int main() {

    int n, m;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    m = fib(n);
    printf("%d", m);

    return 0;
}
```

OR you make a `function prototype` like this before `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int n);

int main() {

    int n, m;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    m = fib(n);
    printf("%d", m);

    return 0;
}

int fib(int n) {

    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if( n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib( n - 2);
}
```

(I prefer the variante with the prototype so that your main is always at the top of your file and you see with the prototype which function's this file includes!)

Comment: after i try your code in sublimetext2,i got "4099 segmentation fault" message.what's wrong with it?

Comment: @chinashieh okay... it should work fine as you can see here: http://ideone.com/3QXNgD ! Can you show the exact error message and what you entered in, please! (Also which code example did you copied?1,2)

Comment: i tried the first code,i just paste it into the sublimetext2.and i got the "4099 segmentation fault"message.Is there anything wrong with my sublimetext2?

Comment: @chinashieh Which compiler do you use? Because sublime is only the editor so that can't be the cause!

Comment: @chinashieh , what's your input and expected output?

Comment: `{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-Wall", "-Wextra", "-pedantic", "-std=c++11",   "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}`this is the build system i am using.and compiler is gcc and g++.

Comment: @chinashieh , Nothing is wrong with GCC or Sublime text. It is your program which has some problem. You might be running out of stack space,you might be causing an infinite recursion,etc etc . So provide the input as well as the expected output of your program.

Comment: @CoolGuy ,so here i have another question, how to open a command window for input in sublimetext2? maybe this is the original reason,because when i run the program,it didn't make me input something while in other IDE i have.I am new to sublimetext2.

Comment: @chinashieh How do you mean `command window for input in Sublimetext2`? And you want to tell me that if you run the program out of sublimetext you can't make a input?

Comment: sorry, it's command line window,and actually,if i run the program in other IDE i will get a command line window which you input something for the program to run and get the result.

Comment: @chinashieh So you have the code (let's take code box 1) in `sublimetext 2` as a `*.c` (`fib.c`) file saved and you compile your program with: `gcc PATH/fib.c - o fib.exe`(PAth is the path to the .c file) Does this work for you?

Comment: i got an error that said "no such file or directory".my os is ubuntu, and is there an easy way for you to compile the program in sublimetext2,for example, in other IDE, when i build and run the program , i usually get a command line window for me to input something and get result.

Comment: @chinashieh With ubuntu you should be able to do this: `gcc fib.c -o fib` and the do this: `./fib` (Maybe you have to set chomd) Does this work?

Comment: oh, i understand something,there is something wrong with your "gcc PATH/fib.c - o fib.exe",you add a more space between "-" and "o",i just compile it for another time,and it works,but don't you believe that it's a little bit tedious? wait for you easy way.

Comment: @chinashieh Uh the space was a mistake! But does it work now?

Comment: it does work now,and i got an idea that should i install a debugger in sublimetext2,then i will be able to do what i expect,besides a debugger, what else do i need to install to make sublimetext2 into a powerful c/c++ ide?